# Trying to run WEBrick for Rails application, but keep getting error: "Only one usage of each socket..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, webrick

Info: Rails 3.0.9; Ruby 1.8.7; Windows 7

I just switched from mysql to postgresql in my Rails environment, and I cannot for the life of me get around this error when trying to run rails s on port 3000:

*WARN TCPServer Error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2)*

I'm developing back and forth between two computers using dropbox, and everything works just fine on my home computer. But at work, this issue is driving me crazy.

I've researched this question all over the internet, and I don't feel any of the answers have applied. The obvious answer is that the port is occupied. But I can't identify anything in my processes or using netstat in the command prompt that would be using this port.

This link http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/MysteryProcessHoldsOntoWebrickPort describes my problem exactly, but none of the solutions have worked. I've tried changing the port to 3001 using the -p option, but then I get this error:

*could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "???" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?*

*could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "???" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?*

This same message also appears if I try to run rake db:migrate.

So aside from the methods I've already mentioned, I have no idea how identify and remedy the cause of this error.

I'm somewhat new to programming, so I may be overlooking something. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the postgres server running, on the same host as webrick? If you shutdown postgres, can you get webrick to serve anything that does not connect to the db, like a static asset?

Comment: Postgres is running on the same machine's localhost. And to my knowledge, the postgres server is not running. If I go into the pgAdmin and try to connect using any port other than 3000 (say 5432), I get the same error as stated above "could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Answer (score 1):

I just had a very similar version of your problem. 
Rake db:migrate didn't migrate, it ran and gave no errors or migrating msgs. , the problem seemed to be a discrepancy between rake 9.2.2 and rake 8.7 abbr.  If u run bundle exec rake db:migrate , it may work but didn't not in my case. I ran sudo gem uninstall rake and the bundle install.  It still didn't work. I uninstalled pg 8.7 and reinstalled pg 9.1.1  using homebrew and opened a new RoR file with --freeze and that file rake db:migrates ... But I can't validate in the model. The Validation throws a 500 internal server error - string can't be coerced to integer. The reason I mention all this is because I have just migrated computer to Mac lion and to postgresql. Changing computers we are both. It seems connecting postgresql is the common thread among these errors. A lot differing opinions about where to put pg files and how best to configure ... I'm on 5432 btw , saves, queries , just don't validate